# axios not sending json data

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to post some json data using axios. The `axios.post` method works well:

```
axios.post(
    "http://localhost/api",
    {"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}
)
```

However, the following code does not work:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost/api',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}
});
axiosInstance.request()
```

The backend is a Flask app, which cannot receive any data. It cannot even read the 'Content-type' header.
So what is the difference between the above two codes? Any idea how to modify the second method so it can work?

Comment: `{"k1":"v1","k2","v2"}` => `{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}` ?

Comment: this is typio your json data invalid due to mix of : ,

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the problem. There is no typo in the actual code. I made this typo when I post this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fail to receive data on backend

```
  let iidd = axios.create({
    baseURL: '/iidd',
    method: 'POST',
    data:{'ll': 'ok'}
  })
  iidd.request({}).then(res=>{
    console.log(res);
  })
```

========================================================

Can receive data on backend

```
  let iidd = axios.create({
    baseURL: '/iidd',
    method: 'POST'
  })
  iidd.request({data:{'ll': 'ok'}}).then(res=>{
    console.log(res);
  })
```

mh....In this result, maybe create axios instance couldn't have default data. but is weird, in axios doc they are [config] too, It should have same result.

Comment: This is correct! Just tried and worked. Well... axios doc is quite confusing. It seems `create` method only creates an axios instance, but the data payload needs to be specified in alias methods... Anyway, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are trying to send is not a JSON.

`{"k1":"v1","k2","v2"}` should be changed to `{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}`

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the problem. There is no typo in the actual code. I made this typo when I post this question.

Answer (score 0):

You should stringify data before sending.

`data: JSON.stringify({"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"})`